# Dynamically adding functions to array columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I'm trying to dynamically add function calls to fill in array columns. I will be accessing the array millions of times so it needs to be quick.

I'm thinking to add the call of a function into a dictionary by using a string variable

```
numpy_array[row,column] = dict[key[index containing function call]]
```

The full scope of the code I'm working with is too large to post here is an equivalent simplistic example I've tried.

```
def hello(input):
    return input

dict1 = {}

#another function returns the name and ID values
name = 'hello'
ID = 0

dict1["hi"] = globals()[name](ID)
print (dict1)
```

but it literally activates the function when using

```
globals()[name](ID)
```

instead of copy pasting hello(0) as a variable into the dictionary.

I'm a bit out of my depth here.
What is the proper way to implement this?

Is there a more efficient way to do this than reading into a dictionary on every call of

```
 numpy_array[row,column] = dict[key[index containing function call]]
```

as I will be accessing and updating it millions of times.

I don't know if the dictionary is called every time the array is written to or if the location of the column is already saved into cache.

Would appreciate the help.

**edit**

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is initialize some arrays, dictionaries, and values with a function

```
def initialize(*args):
  create arrays and dictionaries
  assign values to global and local variables, arrays, dictionaries
```

Each time the initialize() function is used it creates a new set of variables (names, values, ect) that direct to a different function with a different set of variables.

I have an numpy array which I want to store information from the function and associated values created from the initialize() function.

So in other words, in the above example hello(0), the name of the function, it's value, and some other things as set up within initialize()

What I'm trying to do is add  the function with these settings to the numpy array as a new column before I run the main program.

So as another example. If I was setting up hello() (and hello() was a complex function) and when I used initialize() it might give me a value of 1 for hello(1).
Then if I use initialize again it might give me a value of 2 for hello(2).
If I used it one more time it might give the value 0 for the function goodbye(0).

So in this scenaro let's say I have an array

```
    array[row,0] = stuff()
    array[row,1] = things()
    array[row,2] = more_stuff()
    array[row,3] = more_things()
```

Now I want it to look like

```
    array[row,0] = stuff()
    array[row,1] = things()
    array[row,2] = more_stuff()
    array[row,3] = more_things()
    array[row,4] = hello(1)
    array[row,5] = hello(2)
    array[row,6] = goodbye(0)
```

As a third, example.

```
def function1():
    do something
    
def function2():
    do something
    
def function3():
    do something
    
numpy_array(size)

initialize():
    do some stuff
    
    then add function1(23) to the next column in numpy_array
    
initialize():
    do some stuff
    
    then add function2(5) to the next column in numpy_array
    
    
initialize():
    do some stuff
    
    then add function3(50) to the next column in numpy_array
```

So as you can see. I need to permanently append new columns to the array and feed the new columns with the function/value as directed by the initialize() function without manual intervention.

So fundamentally I need to figure out how to assign syntax to an array column based upon a string value without activating the syntax on assignment.

**edit #2**

I guess my explanations weren't clear enough.
Here is another way to look at it.

I'm trying to dynamically assign functions to an additional column in a numpy array based upon the output of a function.

The functions added to the array column will be used to fill the array millions of times with data.

The functions added to the array can be various different function with various different input values and the amount of functions added can vary.

I've tried assigning the functions to a dictionary using exec(), eval(), and globals() but when using these during assignment it just instantly activates the functions instead of assigning them.

```
numpy_array = np.array((1,5))

def some_function():
    do some stuff
    return ('other_function(15)')

#somehow add 'other_function(15)' to the array column.
numpy_array([1,6] = other_function(15)
```

The functions returned by some_function() may or may not exist each time the program is run so the functions added to the array are also dynamic.

Comment: You can't put a function call into a dictionary. A call is syntax, not data, but it evaluates to a value. You might actually want a [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), but it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish exactly. Could you [edit] and add some more context? Like for example, what array library are you using, NumPy? What does the array access loop look like? What does `hello()` actually do? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. See also [mre] and [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: Just to be clear, if you're using NumPy, and that function is verbatim, you could skip the call entirely and just do `array[:] = ID`

Comment: BTW, `input` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). Use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `inp` or `input_`.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what exactly you want to do and why. Where are the function names coming from? It is customary to make a `dict` of functions, and then use values such as `fun_dict.get(fun_name, identity)(*fun_args)`. In any case, you need a source for the `fun_name`. It's unclear from your question where the function names come from at use time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what the OP is after, but here is a way to make an indirection of functions by name:

```py
def make_fun_dict():
    magic = 17
    
    def foo(x):
        return x + magic
    
    def bar(x):
        return 2 * x + 1
    
    def hello(x):
        return x**2
    
    return {k: f for k, f in locals().items() if hasattr(f, '__name__')}

mydict = make_fun_dict()

>>> mydict
{'foo': <function __main__.make_fun_dict.<locals>.foo(x)>,
 'bar': <function __main__.make_fun_dict.<locals>.bar(x)>,
 'hello': <function __main__.make_fun_dict.<locals>.hello(x)>}

>>> mydict['foo'](0)
17
```

Example usage:

```py
x = np.arange(5, dtype=int)
names = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'foo', 'hello']

>>> np.array([mydict[name](v) for name, v in zip(names, x)])
array([17,  3,  4, 20, 16])
```

Comment: Yes, that is similar to what I want, at least the part where I am able to call the function in the dictionary. Check my second edit of the main post.  But none of the functions will be inside locals unfortunately.
I tried adapting your code for globals but I couldn't get it to work.


Also I will be calling the dictionary millions of times and I require speed. Is there a way to do with in a numba compatible fashion?